# Control.Select method not selecting control when using Telerik RadWizard Next() event using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I'm using a `Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadWizard` and `Next` event to switch between pages. On the second page I have a `RadGroupBox` which contains a `RadTextBox`. If the user moves to the second page the `RadTextBox` should be selected automatically. For this I'm using `Control.Select()` method. So my code looks like this:

```
private void radWizard1_Next(object sender, WizardCancelEventArgs e)
{
    radTextBox1.Select();
}
```

But unfortunately, the textbox gets not selected. First, I thought there is something wrong in my application so I created a test application. In the test application I tried selecting the textbox on a button click.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    radTextBox1.Select();
}
```

On button click it works fine. So I removed the button and created a test wizard using the `Next()` event. And to my surprise, the textbox is not selected when moving to the next page.

So I'm sure it's not my main application which is buggy, it must be the wizard or the `Next()` event. Is this a known bug of Telerik `RadWizard`? And is there a solution? Or do you have any other suggestions?

I'm using C# with `Telerik.WinControls` library. All controls in my application are Telerik controls.

**EDIT:**

I also tried `radTextBox1.TextBoxElement.TextBoxItem.HostedControl.Select();`. But this has the same effect. On button click it works fine, on `RadWizard_Next()` it doesn't select the textbox.

**EDIT II:**

When I use `radWizard1.NextButton.Click` event instead of `RadWizard.Next` the textbox get's selected. It's only `Next` event which seems to "block" my code and unselect the textbox.

I could now use `radWizard1.NextButton.Click` without any problems, but I want to know why it's not working on `Next` event. And if there's a possible solution for this event. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next event is triggered when the page is being changed. As the event is cancelable, it gets triggered prior the actual page change, so the sequence is as follows
1. Click next button
2. Trigger event (here you do something)
3. Make the actual change

As the actual change is afterwards, you action is not executed.

You can either use the button click event and you found out, or you can use the SelectedPageChanged event.

Comment: Well, seems legit and really makes sense. Thank you :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.